# Azure: Downloading from Blob Storage results in permissions error?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-worker-roles

I’ve uploaded some files to Blob storage, and now I’m using the OnStart method to retrieve those files and run them.  Right now I’m working locally.

Using the following code:

```
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"C:\testfolder"))
            {
                blob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
            }
```

Results in a “Access to the path 'C:\testfolder' is denied.” error.

What do you think is causing this?  And - will this be an issue once the project is actually pushed up to Azure?  I can change permissions locally, but I'm hoping that once it's actually in a live worker role, it won't be an issue.

Any help would be awesome :)

Comment: @Blam - What makes this *not* a Windows Azure question? The OP is pulling content down from blob storage (meaning Windows Azure Blob storage), and based on the question, the content is either being pulled from the storage emulator or from Windows Azure Blob storage, to a local directory instead of a Windows Azure Web / Worker virtual machine. Finally: the OP never mentioned *migrating* to Windows Azure. I don't see the issue.

Comment: @DavidMakogon The error itself is not an Azure error.  System.IO.File.OpenWrite is not Azure or blob.  He mentions the using is being tested on a client now but will be pushed to Azure Worker Role.

Answer (score 2):

Scratch that - it looks like the C:\testfolder should specify the file name, not the location.  I've changed it to C:\testfolder\test.txt and it works just fine :).